# How to identify 4th occurance of a character using java regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I have two Strings like

```
 aisozp;ak  apso;;   ;pasix acd;XYZ;ao aoz;;  ;aixi o  oiz
 aisozp;ak  apso;;XYZ;pasix acd;098;ao aoz;;  ;XYZ; as oiz
```

Here I need to replace the string XYZ with ABC,only when it exists in between 5th and 6th semicolon (;).
I tried the following thing to achieve this

```
 data.replaceAll("(((.*?);){5})XYZ", "$1ABC")
```

It is working fine with the first string.  But for the second string, it is replacing the string XYZ (last occurrence) which is not followed by 5th semicolon. Here how to restrict the search to 5. Above regex is trying to match XYZ from semicolon 5 and above I guess.
Note: data length between each semicolon is variable.  Could someone help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FWIW, you might want to make the inner groups non-capturing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because your `.` in `.*` matches any character, including `;`.

Replace the `.` with `[^;]` to match any character, except `;`, and add a `^` at the beginning, to force the matching of the `String` from the start:

```
data.replaceAll("^((([^;]*?);){5})XYZ", "$1ABC")
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the anchor `^` which denotes the starting point.

Regex:

```
^((?:[^;]*;){5})XYZ
```

Replacement string:

```
$1ABC
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sE4iH3/7)

```
String s = " aisozp;ak  apso;;   ;pasix acd;XYZ;ao aoz;;  ;aixi o  oiz\n" + 
        " aisozp;ak  apso;;XYZ;pasix acd;098;ao aoz;;  ;XYZ; as oiz";
String m = s.replaceAll("^((?:[^;]*;){5})XYZ", "$1ABC");
System.out.println(m);
```

Output:

```
 aisozp;ak  apso;;   ;pasix acd;ABC;ao aoz;;  ;aixi o  oiz
 aisozp;ak  apso;;XYZ;pasix acd;098;ao aoz;;  ;XYZ; as oiz
```